# How to use ng-repeat on objects and columns?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am wondering how can I use tables - or divs, to create a table, that will display the following table:

```
|            | Season 1    | Season 2     |   ....up to season N    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|                         |
| Title 1    | season.1.1  |  season.2.1  |                        |
| Title 2    | season.1.2  |  season.2.1  |                         |
| Title 3    | season.1.3  |  season.2.1  |                         |
| Title 4    |     ...     |      ...     |                         |
| Title 5    |     ...     |      ...     |                         |
| Title 6    |     ...     |      ...     |                         |
```

My object structure is just like in table. I was trying to do this table with the following:

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Season 1</th>
            <th>Season 2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <th>....</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

However, this would not fit my data structure.

Any ideas on how to tackle this question?Of course, I want to use as much angular functions as possible - ng-repeats.

Thanks

Comment: format your data in the a controller/service so it'll be easier to use with ng-repeat

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, and then use ng-repeat on <th> ?

Comment: try creating a plnkr with some sample data, so others can help more easily

Comment: do you want to have dynamically table in your "thead" and "tbody", right?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use something like [ngTable](http://ng-table.com/)? And **please** post your data structure as it is in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have clarified you data structure more. But look at this and see if it is what you want or modify it according to your needs:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.titles=['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3'];
   $scope.seasons=['Season1', 'Season2', 'Season3'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <table>
 <thead>
   <th></th>
   <th ng-repeat="s in seasons">{{s}}</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="t in titles">
     <td>{{t}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="s in seasons">{{s}}</td>
   </tr>
   
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is dynamic Model for table:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="th in tableData.thead">{{th.title}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="tbody in tableData.tbody">
      <tr ng-repeat="tr in tbody">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr">{{td.content}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("app", []);
    angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.tableData = {
        //we have one thead in the table with 1 tr
        thead: [
          {
          title: ""
        },
          {
          title: "session 1"
        }, {
          title: "session 2"
        }, {
          title: "session 3"
        }],
        //we have 1 tbody in the table with "n" tr
        tbody: [
          {
          tr: []
        },
          {
          tr: [
            {
            content: "Title 1"
          },
            {
            content: "session 1"
          }, {
            content: "session 2"
          }, {
            content: "session 3"
          }]
        }, {
          tr: [
            {
            content: "Title 2"
          },
            {
            content: "session 1"
          }, {
            content: "session 2"
          }, {
            content: "session 3"
          }]
        }, {
          tr: [
            {
            content: "Title 3"
          },
            {
            content: "session 1"
          }, {
            content: "session 2"
          }, {
            content: "session 3"
          }]
        }]
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.It is working for seasons with different lengths of titles and it's fully dynamically working.

Check it out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqUCFQtfIcpn9hq1hlIr?p=preview

The HTML code:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table>
    <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th ng-repeat="s in seasons">{{s.name}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>
        <div ng-repeat="s in  maxtitle().title">title{{$index+1}}</div>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="s in  seasons">

        <div ng-repeat="t in  s.title">
          {{t}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.seasons = [{
    name: "Season1",
    title: ["1title1", "1title2", "1title3"]
  }, {
    name: "Season2",
    title: ["2title1", "2title2", "2title3", "2title4"]
  }, {
    name: "Season3",
    title: ["3title1", "3title2", "3title3"]
  }];

  $scope.maxtitle=function()
  {
    var max=0;
    var position=0;
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.seasons.length; i++) 
    {
     if( $scope.seasons[i].title.length>=max)
     {
       max= $scope.seasons[i].title.length;
       position=i;
     }
    }
    return $scope.seasons[position];
  }
});
```